# Saving datetime in UTC isn't accurate sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

In general, best practice when dealing with dates is to [store them in UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532962/426935) and convert back to whatever the user expects within the application layer.

That doesn't necessarily work with future dates, particularly where the date/time is specific to the user in their timezone. A schedule based on local time requires storing a local time.

In my instance,there’s one attribute that’s a timestamp containing the start_time of a future event, compared to everything else that's now or in the past (including the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps).

### Why

This particular field is the timestamp of a **future event** where the user selects the time.

For future events, it seems best practice is [not to store UTC](http://www.creativedeletion.com/2015/03/19/persisting_future_datetimes.html).

> Instead of saving the time in UTC along with the time zone, developers can save what the user expects us to save: the wall time.

When the user chooses 10am, it needs to stay 10am even when the user’s offset from UTC changes between creation and the event date due to daylight savings.

So, in June 2016, if a user creates an event for 1st Jan 2017 at midnight in Sydney, that timestamp will be stored in the database as `2017-01-01 00:00`. The offset at time of creation would be +10:00, but at the time of the event, it’d be +11:00.. unless government decides to change that in the meantime.

Like wise, I’d expect a separate event that I create for 1 Jan 2016 at midnight in Brisbane to also be stored as `2017-01-01 00:00`. I store the timezone i.e. `Australia/Brisbane` in a separate field.

### What’s a best practice way to do this in Rails?

I’ve tried lots of options with no success:

#### 1. Skip conversion

Problem, this only skips conversion on *read*, not writing.

```
self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:start_time]
```

#### 2. Change the whole app configuration to use `config.default_timestamp :local`

To do this, I set:

**config/application.rb**

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

**app/model/event.rb**

```
...
self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:start_time]
before_save :set_timezone_to_location
after_save :set_timezone_to_default

def set_timezone_to_location
  Time.zone = location.timezone
end

def set_timezone_to_default
  Time.zone = 'UTC'
end
...
```

To be frank, I’m not sure what this is doing.. but not what I want.

I thought it was working as my Brisbane event was stored as `2017-01-01 00:00` but when I created a new event for Sydney, it was stored as `2017-01-01 01:00`even though it displays as midnight correctly in the view.

That being the case, I’m concerned that still have the same problem with the Sydney event that I’m trying to avoid.

#### 3. Override the getter and setter for the model to store as integer

I’ve tried to also store the event start_time as an integer in the database.

I tried doing this by monkey patching the Time class and adding a `before_validates` callback to do the conversion.

**config/initializers/time.rb**

```
class Time
  def time_to_i
    self.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M').to_i
  end
end
```

**app/model/event.rb**

```
before_validation :change_start_time_to_integer
def change_start_time_to_integer
  start_time = start_time.to_time if start_time.is_a? String
  start_time = start_time.time_to_i
end

# read value from DB
# TODO: this freaks out with an error currently
def start_time
  #take integer YYYYMMDDHHMM and convert it to timestamp
  st = self[:start_time]
  Time.new(
    st / 100000000,
    st / 1000000 % 100,
    st / 10000 % 100,
    st / 100 % 100,
    st % 100,
    0,
    offset(true)
  )
end
```

### Ideal Solution

I’d like to be able to store a timestamp in its natural datatype in the database so queries don’t get messy in my controllers, but I can’t figure out how to store “wall time” that doesn’t convert.

Second best, I’d settle for the integer option if I have to.

How do others deal with this? What am I missing? Particularly with the "integer conversion" option above, I'm making things far more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: I'm not a Rubyist, so I'll let someone else answer. But did want to validate that you are correct - scheduling a future event usually requires local time because the events are usually *stated* in terms of local time.

Comment: There's 4 hours till the bounty closes. I've realised a bounty may not've been the best way forward as there really isn't a good answer. I've had to already implement a solution and wish I could now keep this open-ended in case a genuine solution becomes officially available in the future. Everything proposed below is a workaround/hack, which is similar to how I also had to implemented it at the start of the week too so I could meet a deadline. I will accept the solution that's most pragmatic and practical that'll get the job done even if it is still a little cringe-worth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I propose that you still use the first option but with a little hack: in essence, you can switch off the time zone conversion for the desired attribute and use a custom setter to overcome the conversion during attribute writes.

The trick saves the time as a **fake UTC time**. Although technically it has an UTC zone (as all the times are saved in db in UTC) but ***by definition*** it shall be interpreted as local time, regardless of the current time zone.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:start_time]

  def start_time=(time)
    write_attribute(:start_time, time ? time + time.utc_offset : nil)
  end
end
```

**Let's test this in rails console:**

```
$ rails c
>> future_time = Time.local(2020,03,30,11,55,00)
=> 2020-03-30 11:55:00 +0200

>> Model.create(start_time: future_time)
D, [2016-03-15T00:01:09.112887 #28379] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-03-15T00:01:09.114785 #28379] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO `models` (`start_time`) VALUES ('2020-03-30 11:55:00')
D, [2016-03-15T00:01:09.117749 #28379] DEBUG -- :    (2.7ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Model id: 6, start_time: "2020-03-30 13:55:00">
```

Note that Rails saved the time as a 11:55, in a "fake" UTC zone.

Also note that the time in the object returned from `create` is wrong because the zone is converted from the "UTC" in this case. You would have to count with that and reload the object every time after setting the `start_time` attribute, so that the zone conversion skipping can take place:

```
>> m = Model.create(start_time: future_time).reload
D, [2016-03-15T00:08:54.129926 #28589] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-03-15T00:08:54.131189 #28589] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO `models` (`start_time`) VALUES ('2020-03-30 11:55:00')
D, [2016-03-15T00:08:54.134002 #28589] DEBUG -- :    (2.5ms)  COMMIT
D, [2016-03-15T00:08:54.141720 #28589] DEBUG -- :   Model Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `models`.* FROM `models` WHERE `models`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
=> #<Model id: 10, start_time: "2020-03-30 11:55:00">

>> m.start_time
=> 2020-03-30 11:55:00 UTC
```

After loading the object, the `start_time` attribute is correct and can be manually interpreted as local time regardless of the actual time zone.

*I really don't get it why Rails behaves the way it does regarding the `skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes` configuration option...*

**Update: adding a reader**

We can also add a reader so that we automatically interpret the saved "fake" UTC time in local time, without shifting the time due to timezone change:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  # interprets time stored in UTC as local time without shifting time
  # due to time zone change
  def start_time
    t = read_attribute(:start_time)
    t ? Time.local(t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec) : nil
  end
end
```

Test in rails console:

```
>> m = Model.create(start_time: future_time).reload
D, [2016-03-15T08:10:54.889871 #28589] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-03-15T08:10:54.890848 #28589] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `models` (`start_time`) VALUES ('2020-03-30 11:55:00')
D, [2016-03-15T08:10:54.894413 #28589] DEBUG -- :    (3.1ms)  COMMIT
D, [2016-03-15T08:10:54.895531 #28589] DEBUG -- :   Model Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `models`.* FROM `models` WHERE `models`.`id` = 12 LIMIT 1
=> #<Model id: 12, start_time: "2020-03-30 11:55:00">

>> m.start_time
=> 2020-03-30 11:55:00 +0200
```

I.e. the `start_time` is correctly interpreted in local time, even though it was stored as the same hour and minute, but in UTC.

Comment: I've upvoted this as it's somewhat similar to what I implemented. It's still not ideal as rails currently doesn't provide a proper way it would seem to do what's needed. I like what you've suggested as this workaround, so the upvote should get you bounty points.

Comment: Thank you. I agree that this is not an ideal solution. Personally I really don't understand why Rails converts the time zone on writes and not on reads (when using the `skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes` option). It seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Man I've been looking everywhere for this answer. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there's an awesome answer, but I don't think this is just a Rails issue, it's a political and timezone issue. This is the nicest answer for me and it's been 1.5years.. so tick for me to accept I think!

Answer (score 1):

This may sound a bit out there, but I have dealt with similar issues with a recent application I was tasked with - but on the opposite side - when I run an ETL to load data for the application, dates from the source are stored in EST. Rails believes that it is UTC when serving the data, so for that, I converted the dates back to UTC using P/SQL. I did not want these dates to be different than the other date fields within the app.

**Option A**
In this case, could you capture the user timezone at creation, and send that back as a hidden field in the form? I am still learning RoR, so am not sure on the "proper" way to do this, but right now I would do something like this:

Example (I tested this, and it will submit the offset (minutes) in a hidden field):

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.hidden_field :offset %>
</div>

<script>
  utcDiff = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
  dst_field = document.getElementById('timepage_offset');
  dst_field.value = utcDiff;
</script>
```

If you then send utcDiff along with the user selected date, you could calculate the UTC date before storing. I suppose you could add that to the model as well if that data is necessary to know at a later date.

I think that no matter how this is done, there will always be slight area for confusion, unless the user is capable of providing the proper information, which leads me to...

**Option B:**
You could, instead of a hidden field, provide a select list (and to be friendly, default it to the users' local offset), to allow them to provide the zone for which their date is specified in.

**Update - [TimeZone select](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.1.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/time_zone_select)**
I've done some research, and it looks like there is already a form helper for a time zone select box.

Comment: Be sure to read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  Then think about how the offset might change as `new Date()` returns the *current* point in time.

Answer (score 0):

I vote the simplest route and that's saving to UTC. Create a column for country of origin, set up a google alert for "daylight savings time", and if Chile decides to stop using daylight savings or alter it in some crazy way,  you can adapt by querying your database for Chilean users and adjusting their dates accordingly with a script. Then, you can use Time.parse with the date, time and timezone. To illustrate, here are the results the day before daylight savings and after daylight savings on 3/13/2016:

```
Time.parse("2016-03-12 12:00:00 Pacific Time (US & Canada)").utc
=> 2016-03-12 20:00:00 UTC
Time.parse("2016-03-14 12:00:00 Pacific Time (US & Canada)").utc
=> 2016-03-14 19:00:00 UTC
```

This will get you a list of the accepted time zone names:

```
timezones = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.values.collect{|tz| tz.name}
```

Comment: That's not the simplest route.  The OP and [the linked blog post](http://www.creativedeletion.com/2015/03/19/persisting_future_datetimes.html), and several other references are all correct - A schedule based on local time requires storing a local time.  Converting to UTC is introducing data based on the assumption that things won't change in the future - which is a common delusion.